# Effect of increasing the capacity of an edge in a flow network with known max flow

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow, weighted-graphs

I need your help with an exercise on [Ford-Fulkerson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm).

> Suppose you are given a flow network with capacities $(G,s,t)$ and you are also given the max flow $|f|$ in advance.
>
> Now suppose you are given an arc $e$ in $G$ and suppose this arc's capacity is increased by one.
>
> Give an efficent algorithm which returns true iff the increase of the capacity of the arc $e$ will allow an increase in the max flow.

I suppose we shouldn't run Ford-Fulkerson again but somehow use the given $|f|$… Any ideas how?

Comment: This is a standard homework exercise.

Comment: I would argue that this question, as it stands, is under-specified.  Ford-Fulkerson is an efficient algorithm, so simply rerun it and compare to $|f|$.

Comment: Do you mean that you are given the *flow* (the amount sent on all edges) or only the *value* of the flow (the total amount that can be sent from source to sink)?  Also, what's the source of this exercise?  It's considered polite to [reference the source]()http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing of material written by others that you are using in your question.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/86801/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/65318/755

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that you are given the flow on each edge which corresponds to the maximum flow for the graph $G$. So $f_e$ is the flow on edge $e$.

I am also assuming that all the capacities and flows values are integral.

Now given this information, capacity of an edge $e$ is increased by 1. Therefore, the mincut value can increase by at most 1 implying that the maxflow can increase by at most 1.

Thus, find the residual graph and check if there is an augmenting path $P$ from $s$ to $t$. If such a $P$ exists, then increase your maxflow by augmenting this path, otherwise the current flow is still the maximum.

Comment: The question just says that you're given the size of the maximum flow, not the flows on each edge.

Comment: Yes, I assumed some extra information. Should I remove my answer?

Comment: I don't think you need to delete it but it's probably best to stick to questions you can answer without extra assumptions. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: This seems to run in $O(|V|+|E|)$.  Can it be done in $O(|E|)$?