# How to find max flow in a graph after decrementing an edge capacity?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow

We're given a graph $G=(V, E)$, with source $s$ and sink $t$, $s\neq t$, and that all capacities are non-negative integers. Also the max flow itself is given, so we receive the value of max flow for each edge.  We're also given some edge $e'$.

How can the max flow be found if we decrement the capacity value of an edge $e'$ by $1$ in **linear** time?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12703/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/65318/755

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the capacity of edge $c(e') \ge f(e') + 1$ i.e. the max flow remains the same, there is no chance max flow increase, as it would increased without decreasing $c(e')$.

Suppose that $c(e') = f(e')$ (this edge is saturated) and we decrease the capacity in $1$ unit. You need to remove one unit of flow from $s$ to $t$ that goes through edge $e'$. Let say that $e'= (u,v)$.

**Removing flow:** Just run two **BFS**, one starting from $s$ to $u$ going through edges that has flow greater that $0$, the other from $v$ to $t$ equally from edges that has flow greater than $0$. (It is guaranteed you will reach your goal in both cases since there is a unit of flow traversing this edge). Select a path from $s$ to $u$ and remove $1$ unit of flow from each edge and do the same with a path from $v$ to $t$. Complexity: $O(|V| + |E|)$

**Recover max flow:** Now we have a valid flow network but not necessarily the network with max flow. So now you just need to run one iteration of augmenting path with the capacity of edge $e'$ reduced. (Just like running one iteration of Ford-Fulkerson algorithm) Running just one iteration has the complexity of a single **DFS** which is $O(|V| + |E|)$.

Overall complexity of this approach would be $O(|V| + |E|)$ which is **linear** in the amount of nodes and edges.

Comment: How do we know that only one iteration of Ford-Fulkerson will be enough?

Comment: Because flow will augment in at most one unit.

Comment: in the removing flow stage what if the edges adjacent to $u$ and/or $v$ have flow of exactly one?

Comment: What would be the problem in that case? the flow in all in the path from $s-u$ and $v-t$ get decreased by $1$ unit. If it was exactly $1$ the new flow is $0$.

Comment: @Yos I make a mistake, I didn't mean greater than 1, but greater than 0 (greater or equal than 1)

Comment: Is there any way to do this in $O(|E|)$?

Comment: @Addem actually this solution is $O(|E|)$ since you are only traversing the graph using dfs/bfs three times starting from a fixed node (you don't need to iterate over the nodes).

Comment: @Addem I'd also add that one often assumes a network graph is connected so $|E| \geq |V| -1 $ thus $(|| + ||)$  = $(||)$.

Comment: I don't get step ** recover max flow ** . Why would a new augmenting path occur ?

Comment: Check the following graph 
A -> B (cap: 1)
B -> C (cap: 1)
C -> D (cap: 1)
B -> D (cap: 1)

Max flow initially is (1), solution is not unique. If you select A -> B -> C -> D in your solution, and then C -> D capacity is decreased (from 1 to 0). Then a new max flow will appear: A -> B -> D.