# What happens when we increase or decrease capacities in the minimum flow?

Tags: linear-programming, network-flow

I am confused from these 2 true-false questions on the max flow and am seeking clarity on the basics.

- If in a network we **increase** the capacity of an edge in the minimum cut, the maximum
  flow gets increased.
- If in a network we **decrease** the capacity of an edge in a minimum cut, the maximum
  flow gets decreased.

*My thoughts:*

- **Increase** case: I think this is not always true as increasing the minimum could result in what was originally the $2^{nd}$ min flow becoming the lowest value and thus the new max flow. Hence because it isn't always true, the answer is false. This [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/effect-of-increasing-the-capacity-of-an-edge-in-a-flow-network-with-known-max-fl) indicates that max flow needs to be recalculated.
- **Decrease** case: I think this is true because we already have the minimum cut so lowering the minimum brings us to a new minimum. Hence the answer is true.

Is my reasoning correct or is there something I misunderstood.

Comment: I think your reasoning is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1**, increase the weight.  Consider a path on at least three vertices with capacity 1 for every edge.  Max-flow is 1, min-cut is 1.  Increase one of the edges' weight, and the max-flow will still be 1, hence the **claim is false.**

**Case 2**, let $C$ be a minimum cut with cost $w(C)$.  Decrease the weight of one of the edges in $C$ to get a new minimum cost $w'(C)$.  Since $C$ is still a *cut* in the graph, but $w'(C)$ is smaller than any other minimum cut, the **claim is true**.

Comment: If we applied **Case 1** to a generic graph not just one with 3 vertices, could we then have a new max flow (min cut), that is, what used to be the 2nd largest max flow?

Comment: Yes, create a path with edges with weight 1 and 2, and then you increase the weight from 1 to 3.